# ag-grid: key.forEach is not function console error while resizing column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

In my application, i am using ag-grid view. To solve last empty pseudo column issue, i was resizing last displayed column by using 'autoSizeColumns' method of ag-grid. It is working but i am getting console error.

**here is code of resizing last column on initial render**

```
onDataRendered () {
  const colIds = this.gridOptions.api.columnController.getAllDisplayedColumns().map(c => c.colId); 
   const lstColumn = colIds[colIds.length - 1];
   this.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(lstColumn); // problem is here
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }, 50);
},
```

**Error screenshot**

[image: error]

I have tried by changing .map to forEach method but still i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#resizing-example), autoSizeColumns function accept column keys as array so you have to pass it like this only. You have to change your this line from
`this.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(lstColumn);` To `this.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns([lstColumn]);`
and now it should work. Here is working [Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/isY1cF5behSeOLIU)